# C#: Define Class Variable, Default Value and Get Set Not Working?

Tags: c#, class

I'm trying to do something like `public decimal hp = 1000; { get; set; }` but it's not working...

I do know the conventional way to do this would be to create 2 separated variables, one private and one public but is it possible to set a default value and get/set with the same variable? Without having to put the default value in the actual constructor function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible.

But it will be soon!  Take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn683793.aspx)

Auto-Properties will get initializers in C# 6.0.  The syntax will be very close to what you were getting at:

```
public string MyString { get; set; } = "Hello, World!";
```

There's a lot of other cool stuff to be implemented too!

Answer (score 2):

Syntax U try in your question will be provided in C# 6

[http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/08/04/c-6-0-features-part-i-property-initializers.aspx]

But with a little difference:

```
public decimal hp { get; set; } = 1000;
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible. Auto-properties can't be initialized inline.